# flex 3 order of component loading

Tags: flex3, components

i have a custom component (AS3 component) which i include in my main.mxml. The problem is that it takes a bout 2 seconds longer than the main page to load. It has a db call which casues the delay.

how can i fix this so that my custom component is loaded and displayed at the same time as my main.mxml file

this is my component include ;

```
<comp:InputFieldGenerator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're waiting for some asynchronous operation (e.g. a RemoteObject call) to complete, you could wrap your "main page" in a container, set its initial visibility to false and only flip it when your operation completes. You can also use states in your main.mxml for the same effect.